# Using another name for the class object in the django interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I got the following picture of my admin interface:
[image]

My aim is to change the name of "learningObjective object" to something different because it looks pretty bad like this. I prefer to not change the class name of the django model now :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `learningObject` class `__unicode__` method.

Somewhere you have the class and you need to add it the method:

```
class learningObject(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "whatever you want to name it"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn thank you :D I already tried to edit the admin views and templates xP I will accept your answer when I am able too ... in 8 minutes

Comment: @IbrahimApachi glad I could help :) Normally Django is really customizable, you'll almost always find an elegant solution for whatever modification ;)